# Creating a thread in Application Object

Tags: android, thread-safety

I have an Application which, reads files from Sdcard and does some intense processing.

To speed up the user experience

I created a subclass of Application object.
  With in this i created a Thread where, i actually got a reference to the files on Sdcard 
  and did the startup activities so that once the activity is shown there is no lag to the user.

```
public class GAppClass extends Application {

    class setMapDirThread extends Thread {

       public void run() {  
    setMapDir();
       }
   }


  public void onCreate() {

                 setMapDirThread objThread = new setMapDirThread();
         objThread.start();

       }

 private void setMapDir() {

   Log.d(TAG, "Inside initMapComponent");
   String extDirName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
   .getAbsolutePath();
                       /*
                       some processing related to opening and reading files from Sdcard and 
                       allocating cache
                       */

        }
}
```

Is the above mentioned approach safe to use?
i.e. creating thread in the application class to do some background processing is good approach or bad?
Does it slow down application startUp?
Is it safe to create a thread like this to read contents from Sdcard and allocate some memory for internal caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your application does. If it only involves activities, then it should be okay, but it's not recommended (in spite of what you may have read). If your application has services or broadcast receivers, then your application will be created as needed and will launch the caching thread, etc. Consider creating a singleton class as part of your application, in which there are static initializers that can do what you want at startup. That keeps the Application class clean. You could also consider using a method call to your singleton class to initialize the cache, and call that at the very beginning of the onCreate() of the activities that need it. I'm betting your cache would be setup quick enough.

Comment: I have a service which, is created immediately after BootComplete Intent is received. So application object would be created at Boot Up time. And the service is intended to remain all long till the device is powered off.

Comment: Actually creating of cache and reading of files from Sdcard is done by a call to Third party api and it is taking huge time of about 3 secs (i think he is doing some other initialization too). This time is not sustainable during activity startUp.

Comment: what i intend is to speed up the process of initializing without delaying the app or activity startup time, so any suggestions?

Comment: The singleton class just for your caching thread with a static initializer should work, right? This would not require extending the Application class. As I said, it should be safe to extend it, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Yes i can create a singleton class and create Thread to do initialization.                                                      But a couple of issues                                             1) I cant call that function at the start of activity, because it would add to the delay of activity startUp anyways .                2) certain initialization calls for the 3party api, work only in the context of an appl/activity. For this can i extend the singleton class from activity and do the required initialization? But this activity would never be displayed on screen. Will this approach work?

Comment: I don't recommend extending the Activity class; I'd rather you extend the Application class instead. Besides, I don't think that Activity would be completely invisible anyway. If you call the initializer of the singleton class at the beginning of your activity, and the initializer fires off a thread to do the work, that in itself won't add significantly to the startup time of the Activity. You just need a way for the thread to properly update the UI of the activity as it builds out the cache.

Comment: You might want to look at the source code of the Camera app. It uses a thread at the beginning of the main activity to do setup stuff. You'll need to download the Android source code, but this is worth it IMHO. It's free except for the time it will take you to setup for the download and to do the download. But it sure is helpful to be able to see how Google does things. The instructions to get the source code are here: http://source.android.com/source/download.html

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave, but i still have an issue. 3rd party api what i was talking about provides me a customized view. It needs certain init to be done, to show the view on my activity, so even if i create a thread, i cant show my activity until the thread is successfully executed. I may have to show a progress bar or such ...Or i can give a try with asyc task.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems in launching threads to do long running operations. Application class is as good place as any.
You could also use Android's AsyncTask class. It could make your work easier:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I dont think we can create AsyncTask in the Application object, because it would give an exception telling "Cant create Handler which, has not called Looper.prepare".